# loriot - IoT Central connection

Tags: azure-iot-central

How can I connect devices connected to loriot to Azure IoT Central?

I've got the documentation of connecting it to an Azure IoT Hub, but I'm actually using IoT central, so this seems to work differently.

1. Log in to the Azure portal (Microsoft Azure account required).
2. Create a IoT Hub
3. Copy Shared access primary key from IoT Hub > Settings > Shared
   access policies > device
4. Use this primary key and the IoT Hub Name to configure your LORIOT
   application output
5. From IoT Hub > Explorers > IoT devices: create a device using the
   Device EUI as Device ID
6. Messages will have the following format:
   https://docs.loriot.io/display/LNS5/Uplink+Data+Message

Comment: basically, you have to use either the *https* or *MQTT* output. You will need a device connection string to the underlying IoT Hub of the IoT Central App, so you can get it from the util like is *dps_cstr*  https://github.com/Azure/dps-keygen/tree/master/bin/windows

Answer (score 0):

Loroiot setup only allows "IoT Hub Name" & "Primary Key" which IoT Central application does not expose unless a Device Provisioning Call is made to it from device or API. It is possible to get the device key from Azure CLI or IoT Central portal, but IoTHub name is only via the DPS call.

One option is to get this IoTHub name seperately and then configure Loroiot, but in case of HA/DR the IoTHub name could change (IoT Central manages multiple IoTHubs for HA/DR and scale).

In absence of Loroiot having this functionality, check if its API allows configuration then orchestrate provisioning via script, function, etc.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iot-dps/device/runtime-registration